# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) and 204 Response

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I've been trying to search for a solution for this issue here but I cannot seem to find a duplicate issue. I have a weather command where a user can search by zip code or by city. The city URL works fine when printing the JSON data, but when I enter a zip code for `location`, it gives me a `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` error. I print out the response code and it shows as `204` instead of `200` but when I remove the `if location == int():` statement and the other URL, I don't have any issues printing the zip code JSON data.

Edit: Changing my code from `if location == int()` to `if location.isdigit()` solved the issue.

```
if message.content.lower().startswith('!weather'):
    x = message.content.split(" ", 1)
    location = x[1]
    if location == int():
        url = 'https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily?postal_code={}&days=1&units=I&key=c85e55e66bfa4cb0ad9c21a3a038d59e'.format(location)
    else:
        url = 'https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily?city={}&units=I&key=c85e55e66bfa4cb0ad9c21a3a038d59e'.format(location)
    res = requests.get(url)
    information = res.json()
    print(information)
```

Comment: you should not be changing your question to implement the answer. The question/answer will be come irrelevant and  would not be helpful to anyone else. You should only edit question to provide additional information or fixing issues if any. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

Comment: Thanks, I edited it back to the original code but added an edit disclaimer to explain what I changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be because of the if condition `location == int()` in your code, that will always result in `false` as `int()` will always give you `0` unless the intended `location value is 0`. you can check this by swapping city and postal code url.

The [int()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int) is used to get the integer value of a given number or string. Using it without any value will always return `0`.

Comment: Thank you for this bit of information. I'm always learning and this helps. I changed my code to `if location.isdigit():` and now it works great. Thanks again.